# Image Retrieval and Storage Results in Too Much RAM Usage

Tags: java, image, memory, jar, ram

I've searched several days for a viable and reasonable solution for interfacing with my game as far as streamlining my memory usage with images. I was profiling my 2D Turn-based Strategy when I noticed that it was requiring far too much RAM. My problem is simply how do I turn my game resources, which total to a JAR size of 36MB, from 600-800MB RAM to a more expected number of 50MB in run-time. I've seen that the removal of my MediaTracker greatly reduces the RAM and I know that it is necessary. I have no other class that messes with images other than to reference this static class to use the already stored images.

Without further ado I will provide my code, which I hope you will find is easy to read.

```
package editor;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author Darryl Thomas Idle
 */
public final class ResourceStash {

public static Map<String, Image[]> CHARMAP;
public static Map<String, Image[]> ITEMMAP;
public static Map<String, Sound>   SOUNDS;
public static Map<String, Image[]> TILEMAP;
public static Map<String, Image> UIMAP;
public static Map<String, Image> GLARES;
public Font font;

protected EditorEngine engine;
protected MediaTracker media;

public ResourceStash(EditorEngine engine){
    CHARMAP = new HashMap<>();
    SOUNDS = new HashMap<>();
    TILEMAP = new HashMap<>();
    ITEMMAP = new HashMap<>();
    UIMAP = new HashMap<>();
    GLARES = new HashMap<>();
    this.engine = engine;
    media = new MediaTracker(engine);
    try{
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("fonts/EngineerHand.ttf"));
        addSound(SOUNDS, "button_press.wav");
        addSound(SOUNDS, "ambience.mp3");
        addSound(SOUNDS, "grass_step.mp3");
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKDL, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKUL, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKUR, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKDR, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDDL, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDUL, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDUR, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDDR, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPDL, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPUL, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPUR, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPDR, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1DL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1DR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1UL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1UR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A2DL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A2DR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A2UL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A2UR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A3DL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A3DR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A3UL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A3UR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A4DL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A4DR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A4UL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A4UR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A5DL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A5DR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A5UL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A5UR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A6DL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A6DR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A6UL,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A6UR,  CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.DEATHDL, CharacterObject.DUSKWITCH, 10);

        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKDL, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKUL, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKUR, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKDR, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDDL, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDUL, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDUR, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDDR, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPDL, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPUL, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPUR, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPDR, CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1DL,  CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1DR,  CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1UL,  CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1UR,  CharacterObject.TINKERER, 10);

        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKDL, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKUL, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKUR, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKDR, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDDL, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDUL, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDUR, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDDR, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPDL, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPUL, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPUR, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPDR, CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1DL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1DR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1UL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1UR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A2DL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A2DR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A2UL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A2UR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A3DL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A3DR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A3UL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A3UR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A4DL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A4DR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A4UL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A4UR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A5DL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A5DR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A5UL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A5UR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A6DL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A6DR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A6UL,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A6UR,  CharacterObject.HOPLITE, 10);

        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKDL, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKUL, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKUR, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.WALKDR, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDDL, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDUL, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDUR, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMDDR, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPDL, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPUL, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPUR, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.JUMPDR, CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1DL,  CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1DR,  CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1UL,  CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addAnimation(CHARMAP, CharacterObject.A1UR,  CharacterObject.SHADOWYCONTENDER, 10);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "AIR", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "DIRT", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "DIRT_SEL", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "COBBLE", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "COBBLE_SEL", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "FROST", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "FROST_SEL", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "GRASS", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "GRASS_SEL", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "SAND", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "SCORCHED", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "SCORCHED_SEL", 1);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "WATER", 30);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "WATER_SEL", 30);
        addTileImgs(TILEMAP, "LAVA", 30);
        addItemImgs(ITEMMAP, "TREE", 1);
        addItemImgs(ITEMMAP, "TREE_SEL", 1);
        addItemImgs(ITEMMAP, "SPAWN", 1);
        addItemImgs(ITEMMAP, "SPAWN_SEL", 1);
        addItemImgs(ITEMMAP, "BUSH", 1);
        addItemImgs(ITEMMAP, "BUSH_SEL", 1);
        addItemImgs(ITEMMAP, "LIGHT", 1);
        addItemImgs(ITEMMAP, "LIGHT_SEL", 1);
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "mappreview", "leftbutton");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "mappreview", "rightbutton");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "mappreview", "pane");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "layout", "frameui");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "camera", "00");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "portraits", "DUSKWITCH");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "portraits", "HOPLITE");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "portraits", "TINKERER");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "portraits", "SHADOWYCONTENDER");
        addUIImage(UIMAP, "portraits", "UNKNOWN");
        addUIImage(GLARES, "glares", "00");
        int pos = 0;
        for(Entry<String, Image[]> imageEntry: CHARMAP.entrySet()){
            int i = 0;
            for(; i < imageEntry.getValue().length; i++)
                media.addImage(imageEntry.getValue()[i], i+pos);
            pos += i;
        }
        for(Entry<String, Image[]> imageEntry: TILEMAP.entrySet()){
            int i = 0;
            for(; i < imageEntry.getValue().length; i++)
                media.addImage(imageEntry.getValue()[i], i+pos);
            pos += i;
        }
        for(Entry<String, Image[]> imageEntry: ITEMMAP.entrySet()){
            int i = 0;
            for(; i < imageEntry.getValue().length; i++)
                media.addImage(imageEntry.getValue()[i], i+pos);
            pos += i;
        }
        for(Entry<String, Image> imageEntry: UIMAP.entrySet())
            media.addImage(imageEntry.getValue(), pos++);
        media.waitForAll(2000);
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace(System.out);}
}
private void addAnimation(Map<String, Image[]> map, String animation, String characterType, int frameCount){
    try{
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image[] returnImgs = new Image[frameCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){
            Image image = null;
            //System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("images/characters/"+characterType+"/"+animation+"/0"+i+".png").getPath());
            if(i < 10) image = tk.getImage(this.getClass().getResource("images/characters/"+characterType+"/"+animation+"/0"+i+".png"));
            else image = tk.getImage(this.getClass().getResource("images/characters/"+characterType+"/"+animation+"/"+i+".png"));
            returnImgs[i] = image;
        }
        map.put(characterType+animation, returnImgs);
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace(System.out);}
}
private void addItemImgs(Map<String, Image[]> map, String itemType, int frameCount){
    try{
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image[] returnImgs = new Image[frameCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){
            Image image = null;
            //System.out.println(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()+"images/items/"+itemType+"/"+"0"+i);
            if(i < 10) image = tk.getImage(this.getClass().getResource("images/items/"+itemType+"/"+"0"+i+".png"));
            else image = tk.getImage(this.getClass().getResource("images/items/"+itemType+"/"+i+".png"));
            returnImgs[i] = image;
        }
        map.put(itemType, returnImgs);
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace(System.out);}
}
private void addSound(Map<String, Sound> sounds, String soundName){
    try{
        //System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("sounds/"+soundName).toURI().toString());
        Sound sound = new Sound(this.getClass().getResource("sounds/"+soundName).toURI().toString(), false);
        sounds.put(soundName, sound);
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace(System.out);}
}
private void addTileImgs(Map<String, Image[]> map, String tileType, int frameCount){
    try{
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image[] returnImgs = new Image[frameCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){
            Image image = null;
            //System.out.println(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()+"images/tiles/"+tileType+"/"+"0"+i);
            if(i < 10) image = tk.getImage(this.getClass().getResource("images/tiles/"+tileType+"/"+"0"+i+".png"));
            else image = tk.getImage(this.getClass().getResource("images/tiles/"+tileType+"/"+i+".png"));
            returnImgs[i] = image;
        }
        map.put(tileType, returnImgs);
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace(System.out);}
}
private void addUIImage(Map<String, Image> map, String uiName, String partOfUI) {
    try{
        //System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("images/"+uiName+"/"+partOfUI+".png").getPath());
        Image image =   ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("images/"+uiName+"  /"+partOfUI+".png"));
        map.put(uiName+partOfUI, image);
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace(System.out);}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you used a profiler of any sort, even just a heap dump, to determine exactly which objects are consuming memory?

Comment: Yes I used Netbean's Advanced Profiler and it notifies me that it is experiencing a high volume on DataBufferInt[] when it goes to create image storage. I forgot to add that part.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/AIDinKd.png?1 is a link to an image of the stack trace the profiler recorded.

Answer (score 0):

The Java JVM will (by default) allocate quite a large amount of memory for caching and its' own use. You can tune the amount of RAM it will use for [heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) with the `-Xmx` option,

> -Xmx512m

will configure the JVM to not use more than 512 mb for heap. From the linked page,

> **maximum heap**
>
> Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB. Before J2SE 5.0, the default maximum heap size was 64MB. You can override this default using the `-Xmx` command-line option.

Comment: I put those into the run-time arguments already as -Xmx1g it's just that I want to shrink the amount of memory being used because I think there is something I don't know about with underlying image caching.

Comment: And it's using ~800MB... you said you wanted to *reduce* the RAM being used. Try setting it to 512 (or 256) MB. Note, those are still rather larger then your stated **50 MB** target size.

Comment: The 50MB target is not possible with the images being used. But something closer to 500-600MB /might/ be be possible.

Comment: Not with -Xmx1g, because that's one gig.

Comment: Yeah I pulled it down a bit to 500MB and it says OutOfMemory. I've tried all different RAM counts. 800MB-1g is the sweet spot for some reason.

Comment: That is likely because your images alone account for nearly 300MB of memory. With the way java manages the heap for the purposes of fast garbage collection (and whatever else your application is doing) that range of 800MB - 1 GB does not surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

When you read an image into memory, it is kept in memory uncompressed. It appears that all of the images you are reading are png files, which is compressed. This means you are going to consume far more memory than the size of the files.

It appears you have 1200+ images. Likely the least amount of memory utilized will be ~4 bytes per pixel (each pixel represented as an `int`).

Comment: Yeah I have many images for the animations of characters. What would be your recommended approach to reducing the memory consumption? Most the images are 250x250.

Comment: As @ElliotFrisch said, reduce your Xmx value. If you have that set to 1G, you have told the jvm it can use up to 1 GB of memory. You should not be surprised that it chooses to use it. The first step in reducing memory used, is to limit how much the jvm can use.

Comment: Yeah I pulled it down a bit to 500MB and it says OutOfMemory. I've tried all different RAM counts. 800MB-1g is the sweet spot for some reason.